# Valgrind constantly shows memory leak in function

Tags: c, linked-list

Valgrind shows memory leaks of 800 bytes,although I released both strings.

```
void sort(FILE *out) {

int i, j, k, tempBroj;
char* tempKey;
char* tempData;
char* pomoc;
tempKey=calloc(100,4);
tempData=calloc(100,4);

struct pesma *current;
struct pesma *next;

int size = length();
k = size ;

for ( i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i++, k-- ) {
    current = glava;
    next = glava->next;

    for ( j = 1 ; j < k ; j++ ) {
        if(strcmp(current->naslov,next->naslov)>0)

            tempData=current->naslov;
            current -> naslov=next->naslov;
            next->naslov=tempData;

            tempKey=current->folder;
            current->folder =next->folder ;
            next->folder=tempKey;

            tempBroj=current->vreme;
            current -> vreme=next-> vreme;
            next->vreme=tempBroj;
        current = current->next;
        next = next->next;


    }}

free(tempKey);
free(tempData);

}
```

This text is written because:It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: After the `tempData=current->naslov;` line, what has happened to the address of the meory your allocated? Where is it kept? Simialrly for `tempKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory to `tempKey` and `tempData`, but then you later overwrite the values of these pointers:

```
        tempData=current->naslov;     // <------ here
        current -> naslov=next->naslov;
        next->naslov=tempData;

        tempKey=current->folder;      // <------ here
        current->folder =next->folder ;
        next->folder=tempKey;
```

In doing so you loose the pointer values returned from `calloc` causing a memory leak.  This also results in passing values to `free` that were not returned by `calloc`.

You can simply remove the calls to `calloc` and `free`.